# make file compilation error

Tags: makefile

I am trying to compile module for ARM board using cross_compile.
it is showing error as below.
when I am trying to compile for x86 system it is working fine and
creating *.ko file.
I am using make file as below
Make File Code:

```
obj-m += max-mem2.o

#startstop-objs := start.o stop.o

all:
        make -C /home/satishg/qemu/linux-3.2 M=$(PWD) modules


clean:
        make -C /home/satishg/qemu/linux-3.2 M=$(PWD) clean
```

End of Code:

I am changing kernel path to linux kernel source instead of /usr/src/linux/<>/build 
What is going wrong here?

ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.
         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.
         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.

WARNING: Symbol version dump /home/satishg/qemu/linux-3.2/Module.symvers
           is missing; modules will have no dependencies and modversions.

Thank you in advance.
--Satish.G

Comment: FWIW, I can't understand your question.   What do you mean "I am changing kernel path"?   Where does your reference to /usr/src/linux come from?     Have you looked to see if the files that it tells you are missing ...a are missing?   Have you run make oldconfig && make prepare, as it instructed you to do?

Comment: The first thing I'd do is use a macro such as `QEMU = /home/satishg/qemu/linux-3.2` and then use that in the command lines.

Answer (score 0):

First, whenever running make recursively in a makefile you should *never* run `make` explicitly; you should *always* use the `$(MAKE)` variable instead.

Second, the variable `PWD` is not set in your makefile so it will be empty, and `M=$(PWD)` expands to just `M=` which is not right.  Where are you getting that from?  Did you mean to use `M=$(CURDIR)` instead, or is there more to your makefile you're not showing us?

Third, the error message looks pretty clear to me: it seems you've not configured the alternate Linux kernel source tree.  It even gives you the commands that you should run to perform that configuration.